# Inhomogeneous Second Order PDE with cos function

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-differential-equations

$$A\frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial t^2}=B \sin x+k$$

Solve $x$ as a function of $t$.

I found this post [Solving second order differential equation involving sine around function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2332783/solving-second-order-differential-equation-involving-sine-around-function][1])

Trying to solve it the same way. However, it reduces to,

$$ \left(\frac{\partial x}{\partial t} \right)^2=\frac{2(kx-B \cos x)}{A}$$

I am just not sure if there is a close form solution for this.

Comment: This is essentially the [pendulum equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mathematics)). The second equation comes about by multiplying both sides by $\partial_{t} x$ and integrating (there should be another constant in the second expression). But using the result you have, you can then take the square root of both sides and separate into $$\frac{dx}{\sqrt{kx - B \cos(x)}} = \sqrt{\frac{2}{A}} dt$$ which I think only has a solution in terms of special functions.

Answer (score 1):

Almost as @mattos commented, switching variables, the equation write
$$-A \frac{t''}{(t')^3}=B \sin(x)+k$$ Reducing the order $p=t'$
$$-A \frac{p'}{p^3}=B \sin(x)+k\implies p=t'=\pm\frac{\sqrt{A}}{\sqrt{ c_1-2 B \cos (x)+2 k x}}$$ and I do not see any way to go further.